# How to enable paging in ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, report-viewer2010

My ReportViewer does not work properly when I use paging. When I click the next page it just displays the first page (there are several pages). What could be wrong? The version of reportViewer is the latest.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
    <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {            
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SchetReestrDataSet", Model));
              LocalReport LocalReport = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;

    }
}



 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Коллекция)" style="margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%;"  
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"  
    AsyncRendering ="false">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Views\Reports\ReportSchetReestr\Report.rdlc">        
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

The Model data is passed from the controller:

```
IEnumerable data = _unitOfWork.SchetReestrRepo.GetData(...//parameters);
return View(data);
```

The data is displayed correctly, but paging does not work. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: set pagesize it automatically paging in reportviewer

Comment: it does not work at all